# Overwriting Manager in Django using django-cache-machine

Tags: django, django-cache-machine

Since the [django-cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine) override the objects model attribute, the right way to modify the queryset is as follows:

```
class ModelAQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def foo(self):
        return self.filter(name='foo')

class ModelAManager(base.CachingManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelAManager, self).__init__()

    def get_query_set(self):
        return ModelAQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def foo(self):
        return self.get_query_set().foo()

class ModelA(base.CachingMixin, models.Model):
    #fields ...
    objects = ModelAManager()
```

We can do `objects = base.CachingManager` in some model. That means, the `CachingManager` already inherits from `models.Manager` itself. So we just create a model that inherits from base.CachingManager. Right?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this?

Comment: No. Not quite sure, but I think I tested it once, and it worked. It didn't for you?

Comment: I just made my custom manager inherit from base.CachingManager but didn't deal with overriding get_query_set. I'm not 100% sure if it's actually working but it seems to be.

Comment: There's a method in django-cache-machine that says if a queryset is comming from the cache. Check it out, and you'll see if it's working.